# Running multiple Adds in row on ObservableCollection<T> connected to CollectionView causes exception

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency

I have the following code:

```cs
private void UpdateItems(FocusedItemData data)
{
    items.Clear();

    var newItems = new List<ItemViewModel>();

    // (...)

    foreach (var item in newItems)
        items.Add(item);

    // (...)
}
```

`items` is an `ObservableCollection` attached to a `CollectionView`. Upon calling second `items.Add`, I'm receiving an `InvalidOperationException` with message:

```
Collection was modified: enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Why does it happen? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because `items.Add` leads to calling `CollectionChanged`, which is transported by the `CollectionView` to UI. At this point UI starts to update, enumerating the collection, but this happens in a separate thread.

While this happens, second `items.Add` is called, modifying the underlying collection. This breaks the enumerator used by the UI (modifying collection, which is just being enumerated is generally a bad idea).

This is a shortcoming of `ObservableCollection<T>`, which is not thread-safe. A solution may be to write a custom implementation, which, when enumerated, provides current snapshot of the collection instead of directly passing enumerator to underlying data.

Note that this solution will not be too performant, but will solve the problem of changes during enumeration. In addition, UI will capture subsequent `CollectionChanged` events and in the end should contain the actual contents of the collection.

Example implementation:

```cs
public class ObservableList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    // Private fields -----------------------------------------------------

    private readonly List<T> list = new();
    private T[] snapshot = null;
    private object lockObject = new();

    // Private methods ----------------------------------------------------

    private T[] EnsureSnapshot()
    {
        T[] returnSnapshot = snapshot;

        if (snapshot == null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                snapshot ??= list.ToArray();
                returnSnapshot = snapshot;
            }
        }

        return returnSnapshot;
    }

    private void SetItem(int index, T value)
    {
        T oldValue;

        lock(lockObject)
        {          
            oldValue = list[index];
            list[index] = value;
            snapshot = null;
        }

        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, value, oldValue, index));
    }

    private T GetItem(int index)
    {
        return EnsureSnapshot()[index];
    }

    // Public methods -----------------------------------------------------

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        int addedIndex;

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            list.Add(item);
            addedIndex = list.Count - 1;
            snapshot = null;
        }

        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, addedIndex));
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            list.Clear();
            snapshot = null;
        }

        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {            
        return EnsureSnapshot().Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        EnsureSnapshot().CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)EnsureSnapshot()).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)EnsureSnapshot()).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(EnsureSnapshot(), item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            list.Insert(index, item);
            snapshot = null;
        }

        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index));
    }

    public void Move(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        T item;

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            item = list[fromIndex];
            list.RemoveAt(fromIndex);
            list.Insert(toIndex, item);
            snapshot = null;
        }

        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move, item, toIndex, fromIndex));
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        int index = -1;

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            index = list.IndexOf(item);
            if (index < 0)
                return false;

            list.RemoveAt(index);
            snapshot = null;
        }

        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, index));
        return true;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        T item;

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            item = list[index];

            list.RemoveAt(index);
            snapshot = null;
        }

        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, index));
    }

    public int Count => EnsureSnapshot().Length;

    public T[] Snapshot => EnsureSnapshot();        

    public bool IsReadOnly => ((ICollection<T>)list).IsReadOnly;

    public T this[int index] 
    { 
        get => GetItem(index);
        set => SetItem(index, value); 
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```